# JQuery Popup window showup for every user

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

Below is my current code TechHunter. When I click on Yes Button nothing happens, also the popup window looks un-formatted with CSS.

```
<?php do { ?>
<div data-userid="<?php echo $row_users['id']; ?>" class="userTableBody">
    <div id="idRow"><?php echo $row_users['id']; ?></div>
    <div id="usernameRow"><?php echo $row_users['username']; ?></div>
    <div id="useremailRow"><a href="mailto:someone@example.com"><?php echo $row_users['email']; ?></a></div>
    <div id="actionRow"><a href="#" class="toPopupButton actionButton">Delete</a></div>
</div> 
<?php } while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)); ?>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete user?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../include/js/script.js"></script>
```

and this is JQuery code place inside script.js which I took from your example at jsfiddle.net

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:250,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen:false,
      buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:'http://www.example.com/action/deleteUser.php?id='+$( this ).data('userid'),
                success:function(){$this.dialog( "close" )}
            });

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });

    $( ".toPopupButton" ).click(function() {
        var userid = $(this).parentsUntil('.userTableBody').parent().data('userid');
        console.log(userid);
      $( "#dialog-confirm" ).data('userid',userid).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't you mean the $("a.topopup").click(function() event? ( replace the # with a .)?

Comment: yeah and please change ID named toPopup or class topopup, can become really messy

Answer (score 1):

It will never work because you generate multiple elements with same IDs inside your php loop. Convert everything to classes or userId based element IDs.

```
<?php do { ?>
        <div data-userid="<?php echo $row_users['id']; ?>" class="userTableBody">
            <div class="idRow"><?php echo $row_users['id']; ?></div>
            <div class="usernameRow"><?php echo $row_users['username']; ?></div>
            <div class="useremailRow"><a href="mailto:someone@example.com"><?php echo $row_users['email']; ?></a></div>

            <div class="actionRow"><a href="#" class="toPopupButton actionButton">Delete</a></div>
        </div> 


            <!-- Popup window -->
        <div class="toPopup"> 
            <div class="close"></div>
            <span class="ecs_tooltip">Press Esc to close <span class="arrow"></span></span>
            <div class="popup_content">
            <p>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</p>
            <a href="action/deleteUser.php?id=<?php echo $row_users['id']; ?>">Yes</a>


            </div> <!--your content end-->
        </div> <!--toPopup end-->

    <?php } while ($row_users = mysql_fetch_assoc($users)); ?>
```

But I also suggest generating the popup on the fly using jQueryUI Dialog this will make your code a lot cleaner. Fiddle here :

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/LtcUX/

Comment: This is exactly what I need, however when I click on Yes button nothing happens. Another thing is that the popup window design is messed up and its not showing the design like you have at jsfiddle.net. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you help me with this?

Comment: I have included this one http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js and same thing happens again. Is this correct one?

Comment: edit your post and add your new modifications so i can see it. You also need to include jqueryui css

Comment: I have updated the above code and added the one I am currently using. Let me know what needs to be changed. Thanks!

Comment: don't totally change your post like that or we loose track, add a EDIT mention then update below... anyway, same comment as first time, change from id to class inside the WHILE loop, also try using firebug or Google Chrome F12 debugger then go step by step into the code. no error in console?

Comment: have you included jQuery UI CSS?

Comment: Thanks, got the style for popup box back thanks to jQuery UI CSS. I also added classes instead of IDs inside while loop, however, again nothing happens when I click on Yes button inside popup window. The same thing is with your example at jsfiddle.net . It would be great to have when I click on Yes button to be redirected to page specified inside that JQuery code and in my example above to http://www.example.com/action/deleteUser.php?id=SOMETHING

Also Firebug dont show any errors, seems like the action is not triggered when I click on Yes button.

Comment: add console.log('a step description') in every step and see where it does not trigger. in my fiddle the URL does not exist that's why it doesn't work, i hope you changed it with the good one :)

Comment: using Firebug I found whats causing the problem, its session since on that page I am checking if user is logged in. Once I remove the code for session checking the "Yes" button works. Any way I can keep that code and make "Yes" button works too? Or what even better would be is that when I click on "Yes" button to be redirected on that page, is that possible with your code?

Comment: again, post the exact code you are using. you should probably use a $.get to check the session and on success trigger the popup

Answer (score 0):

There are many elements that match this selector:

`$("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500);`

You need to specify which one you want to show.

You could do something like this:

In your click handler, change

`loadPopup(); // function show popup`

to

`loadPopup($(this)); // function show popup`

And change loadPopup() to something like this:

```
function loadPopup($elem) { 
        if(popupStatus == 0) { // if value is 0, show popup
            closeloading(); // fadeout loading
            $elem.closest('.userTableBody').next("#toPopup").fadeIn(0500); // fadein popup div
            $("#backgroundPopup").css("opacity", "0.7"); // css opacity, supports IE7, IE8
            $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn(0001); 
            popupStatus = 1; // and set value to 1
        }   
    }
```

I would recommend refactoring your code a bit though. For standards-compliance, element Id's should be unique. You can add classes to them in order to select them.